# applying padding between two relative layouts

Tags: android

am trying to show two relative layouts by placing padding between them so that
round corner layout will be visible am attching scrren show there the layout is overlappded.so how to make that spacing between them

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


        <RelativeLayout 
           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"  
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/background" >


            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"   android:paddingTop="22dp"     
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"      android:paddingRight="20dp"   android:paddingBottom="20dp"          
                >


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/create" android:paddingTop="10dp" android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"         
                    >


                     <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/phone"   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"    android:layout_below="@+id/last"
                    android:background="#ffffff" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/icon"      android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"      android:src="@drawableicon" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/Phonenumber"  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
                        android:hint="Enter Phone Number" />
                </RelativeLayout>



           </RelativeLayout>


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/contactAddress"    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:layout_below="@+id/create"   android:paddingLeft="10dp"      
                    android:paddingBottom="20dp" android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"  android:paddingTop="20dp" >



                    <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/state" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/city"
                    android:background="#ffffff" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/stateicon"  android:paddingRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:src="@drawable/stateicon" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/enterstate"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/stateicon"
                        android:hint="Enter State" />
                </RelativeLayout>





                </RelativeLayout>



               </RelativeLayout> 


            </RelativeLayout>




<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<RelativeLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"  android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"   android:paddingTop="22dp"     
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"      android:paddingRight="20dp"   android:paddingBottom="20dp"          
        >


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/create" android:paddingTop="10dp" android:paddingBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="10dp" android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"         
            >


             <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/phone"   android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"    android:layout_below="@+id/last"
            android:background="#ffffff" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon"      android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"      android:src="@drawableicon" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/Phonenumber"  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
                android:hint="Enter Phone Number" />
        </RelativeLayout>



   </RelativeLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/contactAddress"    android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:layout_below="@+id/create"   android:paddingLeft="10dp"      
            android:paddingBottom="20dp" android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner"  android:paddingTop="20dp" >



            <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/state" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/city"
            android:background="#ffffff" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/stateicon"  android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:src="@drawable/stateicon" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/enterstate"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/stateicon"
                android:hint="Enter State" />
        </RelativeLayout>





        </RelativeLayout>



       </RelativeLayout> 






    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This XML is completely messed.

First of all, you should properly indent the code, make it a bit more readable. It's good practice, something necessary if you wish to work in (serious) teams.

Second, you have too many relative layouts. `RelativeLayout` is the "heaviest" layout to render. If you want to go this route, which is far from good (catastrophic, really), at least use `FrameLayout` to encapsulate `state` and `phone` relative layouts. Then try margins on inner elements, if padding doesn't work.

Third, if you want to do it decently, avoid this way of doing it. Make background for **one** layout... Rounded corners and all.